how to temporarily disable a parent bones influence
I have a sword in a characters hands, I want them to put it down and move, however the sword's bone is parented to a sheath's bone that is parented to the characters torso bone.
How can I individually move the sword without it's parent bones affecting it?

I want the sword to stay perfectly still in the ground.

You could separate the bone so it's no longer parented to the parent bone and then add a couple of constraints to copy the location and rotation of the original parent

This way it behaves the same as if it was parented but you can turn the constrains on/off

Or you could use a single Child Of constraint which makes it behave exactly like it was parented and then change the Influence value...

@GordonBrinkmann: yeah, but why take a simple way if there is a much more complicated one...!? :D
